# How to detect HTTPS redirection on Azure Websites?

Tags: node.js, azure

As per the title, I have a Node.js application and I want to be able to detect whether a request is being made over HTTPS or HTTP. So far my redirection looks like this:

```
// Ensure the page is secure, or that we are running a development build
if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    res.render('index');
} else {
    winston.info('Request for login page made over HTTP, redirecting to HTTPS');
    res.redirect('https://' + req.host);
}
```

Which works fine on Nodejitsu, but a redirected HTTPS request doesn't have the 'x-forwarded-proto' header set on Azure.

Comment: It's looking like I can make use of the "x-arr-ssl" header.

Comment: As per my understanding,  header "x-forwarded-proto" is coming from some actual client. While redirect some intermittent app which is run those redirect is not include x-forwarded-proto header. I feel better to use some other param to identify the protocol rather than header information.

Comment: What would you suggest using? Azure and Nodejitsu both use proxies to redirect the HTTPS traffic to the HTTP server. There isn't anything else I can use is there?

Comment: have u checked that any auto redirect happen in proxies?

Comment: Yes, I know it does redirect.

Comment: I mean auto redirect to server. If yes, then remove those proxy and hit the server directly from client. And also check both initial request and request on redirect has header "x-forwarded-proto". I'm not sure, but it will give an idea that where header "x-forwarded-proto" is removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I was correct in my comment:

`X-ARR-SSL` seems to be the header to check for.

```
// Ensure the page is secure, or that we are running a development build
if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https' || req.headers['x-arr-ssl'] || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    res.render('index');
} else {
    winston.info('Request for login page made over HTTP, redirecting to HTTPS');
    res.redirect('https://' + req.host);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the exact same issue, but solved it in a different way. If you're using Express and enable trust proxy then req.protocol will pick up the x-forwarded-proto header. Azure doesn't set the x-forwarded-proto header, but you can use the x-arr-ssl header to hack it in manually so that req.protocol will return the correct value in the rest of your app.

Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/freshlogic/6348417

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.enable('trust proxy');

// HACK: Azure doesn't support X-Forwarded-Proto so we add it manually
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.headers['x-arr-ssl'] && !req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']) {
        req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] = 'https';
    }

    return next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE-2021:
This is a very old answer. For a long time there is an option on all app service plans that support Custom domains. Go to the Custom domains blade in the azure portal for the App Service and set the HTTPS only checkbox. This will redirect even before traffic hits the app service.