# How to find the original protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) when doing SSL offloading in Azure WebApp?

Tags: azure, express, azure-web-app-service

We're running Node.js/express.js on Azure WebApp with SSL binding.
It seems like the `req.protocol` always returns `http`.

Is there a way to get the original protocol, i.e. `http/https` according to the original request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16042648/893780

Comment: @robertklep is that the way Azure acts or should the client add these header?

Comment: Azure will probably set one of those headers (most likely the `Front-End-Https` one) to indicate the original protocol. I don't have experience with Azure myself so you have to do a bit of debugging to find out exactly which header you need to check.

Comment: Thanks due to your answer I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15139339/593425  they are using 'x-arr-ssl'